# Troubleshooting "stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate" when splitting AVI in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to split video files and at the same time convert them to mp4 for a website. I have troubles splitting AVI files (flv and mp4 worked fine).

Example:

```
> ffmpeg -i original-1.avi -ss 00:03:00 -t 00:00:20 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -s 416x240 -y 1.mp4

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, avi, from 'original-1.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Nandub v1.0rc2
    INAM            : Rammstein - Links 2-3-4
    ISBJ            : Rammstein - Links 2-3-4
    IART            : 
    ICOP            : Coded by Hermit (DivX 5.0.3) 15.04.06
    ICMT            : 
  Duration: 00:03:34.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1630 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 704x406 [PAR 1:1 DAR 352:203], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 160 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x804215810]using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x804215810]using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x804215810]profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x804215810]264 - core 110 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2010 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=4 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=200 ratetol=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 416x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 26:15], q=10-51, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, 160 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg4 @ 0x804214410]Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
frame=    8 fps=  1 q=405.0 size=       0kB time=0.74 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    
frame=   50 fps=  5 q=37.0 size=      13kB time=0.32 bitrate= 338.7kbits/s    
frame=   65 fps=  6 q=35.0 size=      38kB time=0.92 bitrate= 334.9kbits/s    
frame=   68 fps=  6 q=35.0 size=      43kB time=1.04 bitrate= 342.6kbits/s    
frame=   76 fps=  6 q=35.0 size=      56kB time=1.36 bitrate= 340.3kbits/s    
frame=   92 fps=  7 q=35.0 size=      85kB time=2.00 bitrate= 349.6kbits/s    
frame=  112 fps=  8 q=34.0 size=     118kB time=2.80 bitrate= 346.2kbits/s    
frame=  132 fps=  9 q=35.0 size=     158kB time=3.60 bitrate= 359.8kbits/s    
frame=  151 fps= 10 q=31.0 size=     193kB time=4.36 bitrate= 363.3kbits/s    
frame=  168 fps= 11 q=34.0 size=     223kB time=5.04 bitrate= 362.3kbits/s    
frame=  187 fps= 12 q=34.0 size=     258kB time=5.80 bitrate= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and I am unsure if the command output is complete.

Try forcing a -r in front of the input.

This looks like an issue of an input file and less of ffmpeg.

Also, why decode for 3 minutes before processing?

Here is a brief intro if you are unsure of what your command is actually doing here.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg